# Change default color of UITableView's textLabel and detailTextLabel

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I was hoping there was a way to change the default color of UITableView's text in its cell's `textLabel` and `detailTextLabel` project-wise. Some code in AppDelegate that would change it from black to some other custom color.

The coloring of my app got a bit convoluted and this would be a much simpler solution than explicitly changing it with:

```
cell.textLabel.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
```

Comment: Tamarisk tell me your exact solution

Answer (score 1):

Just create a subclass of UITableViewCell, change the text color, then have all other UITableViewCell subclasses in your app inherit from this "parent" cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `UIAppearance` in the `AppDelegate`

`[[UILabel appearance] setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];`

Replace red color with the color you want. The color will be the default color and you can still override it per label.

Answer (score 0):

add method in AppDelegate.h

```
-(void)SetLabelTextColourForLabel:(UILabel*)Label;
```

add method implementation in AppDelegate.m

```
-(void)SetLabelTextColourForLabel:(UILabel*)Label
{
     [Label setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}
```

and call the method in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
AppDelegate *app= (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    [app SetLabelTextColourForLabel:cell.textLabel];
    [app SetLabelTextColourForLabel:cell.detailTextLabel];
```

hope this will resolve your problem.